# Extreme amenability of topological groups and invariant means

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

Recently I'm reading the paper [Ramsey–Milman phenomenon, Urysohn metric spaces, and extremely amenable groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0004010.pdf) by Pestov. When it comes to the definition of an extremely amenable topological group, it claims (without proof) that

> (the extreme amenability) is equivalent to the existence of a left invariant **multiplicative** mean on the space of all bounded right uniformly continuous functions on the group.

I'm not aware of any references on this result.

**Question:** Is there any reference on extreme amenability of topological groups and invariant means?

Thanks for any comments or answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The action $G\curvearrowright\beta G$ is continuous iff $G$ is discrete, so for nondiscrete groups it is not true that $G$ is extremely amenable iff this action has a fixed point.

What one should look at instead, is the biggest compactification on which $G$ acts continuously, this is known as the Samuel compactification, $S(G)$, and can be constructed as the spectrum of the algebra $RUCB(G)$ of right uniformly continuous bounded functions on $G$. This is where the uniform continuity condition comes from. It is then true that $G$ is extremely amenable iff $G\curvearrowright S(G)$ has a fixed point. (Of course on a discrete group all continuous functions are uniformly continuous so $\beta G$ and $S(G)$ are isomorphic)

Note also that if you write explicitly what it means, for a fixed $f\in C(G)$, that the orbit map $G\to C(G)$, $g\mapsto gf$, is $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-continuous, you'll end up with a uniform continuity condition on $f$!

Pestov wrote a whole book on the subject, called *Dynamics of Infinite-dimensional Groups: The Ramsey-Dvoretzky-Milman Phenomenon*, it is a great introduction to extreme amenability which contains all the details of the above and much more

Comment: Thanks for pointing the missing point out. I forgot to check the continuity of the action on $\beta G$, so I removed the wrong arguments from the thread. This book seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.